# Finite outer islands in the Minecraft End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on a public server with a giant map.

After travelling a huge distance in the End and passing thousands of islands, suddenly there are no more islands. I guess I am at the edge of the [outer-islands-donut](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:EnderIslandsRender.jpg).

**What is the algorithm to determine at which coordinates the outer islands stop generating?**

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End#Outer_islands

> These outer islands generate infinitely‌

If so, why am I travelling through nothing but void space?

Update: I haven't seen any island in the last 20 000 blocks and im still going. I doubt any islands have been removed by worldedit or even by hand. I assume they do not generate infinitely. I don't know which version of MC has been used to generate the map I'm on.

Comment: How are you travelling? if flying, maybe you are above the islands and havent seen them below you. could you give us the coordinates where the islands stopped generating for you along with the seed the server is on if you know it, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Even if you don't know the original version of the server, you know that the chunks you're loading now are from the version the server is on now, since they're being generated as you pass through them (unless you're following the exact course that someone else did on a previous version, which seems slightly improbable ^_^)

Comment: @AMJ The islands stopped at about 300 000 blocks from center and the map is said to be as big as it gets. I'm flying at constant height so im not too high.

Comment: Looking at the render you linked, there is a 1,000 block gap between the main end island and the small end islands. If the end islands stop generating after 300,000 blocks, the render cant have possibly shown that. It's most likely that the render was just not 'squared off' to fill the image.

Comment: try to get the seed and check on creative on single player

Comment: After travelling another 200 000 blocks the islands suddenly started again to generate :-D CRAZY WORLD. It's a public server, seed is not available.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a terrain generation bug in Minecraft, which is at the time of writing still unresolved. The relevant bug report can be found on the Mojang bugtracker: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-159283

Comment: This is a really good link but I noticed the void chunks got fixed on that specific server in 1.16.0 while the linked issue is not yet fixed in 1.16.1

Comment: The bug is very much still present in singleplayer, which is why it's marked as unresolved. Perhaps the server software (Spigot, Paper, etc) of the server you're playing on has fixed it already. I've noticed the same on a Paper server that I play on, no more issues there either.